# How to create Success message with column value displayed in APEX

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have the following table

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Harry | Potter |
| 2 | Hermione | Granger |
| 3 | Ron | Weasley |

I created a button with process that deletes the checkbox selected row and moves it to another table:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (PK_1, first_name, last_name)
SELECT PK, first_name, last_name FROM source_table WHERE PK IN (SELECT column_value FROM apex_string.split(:P3_SELECTED_ID,':'));

DELETE FROM source_table WHERE PK IN (SELECT column_value FROM apex_string.split(:P3_SELECTED_ID,':'));
```

I would like to create a Success message when the rows is deleted which looks like the following:

```
"Ron was successfully moved to another table"
```

What I tried so far?

I created a success message in Process - Identification -Success Message

> first_name was successfully moved to another table

But this does not display the first_name as Ron or any other selected row. How to I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things of importance here

1. To reference something in apex, use page items.
2. The syntax for referencing a page item in html is the `&P_ITEM.` syntax.

So the success message should be something like

```
&P1_FIRST_NAME. was successfully moved to another table
```

Make sure to populate the page item with the value you are deleting from the table. Note that page items are scalar values. To get multiple values, use a comma separated list.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. How can I use the same for Button confirmation message? i.e., before deleting the row. Like "Are you sure you would like to delete Ron?"

Comment: I'd use a dynamic action then for the button. With 1 action of type "Alert" in which you customize the text and a 2nd action of type "Submit"